# angular add data outside ng-repeat

Tags: django, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have an angular app that has the following ng-repeat:

```
<div ng-repeat="detail in mpttdetails">

    <div ng-if="detail.category.id == {{node.id}}" class="list-group">
        {%verbatim%}
            <li class="list-group-item" >
                <div class="row">
                    <div class=".col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2">
                        {{detail.student_academic_credit.course_name}}
                    </div>
                    <div class=".col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-3">
                        {{detail.student_academic_credit.title}}
                    </div>
                    <div class=".col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2">
                        {{detail.student_academic_credit.credit}}
                    </div>
                    <div class=".col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2">
                        {{detail.student_academic_credit.final_grade}}
                    </div>
                    <div class=".col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3">
                        {{detail.student_academic_credit.term}}
                    </div>  
                </div>
            </li>
        {%endverbatim%}

    </div>

</div>
```

My mpttservice here is a service that fetches data from a django app. Here i would like to have a bootstrap badge as:

```
<span class="badge badge-info">{{sum}}</span>
```

just above the ng-repeat such that it adds all the `{{detail.student_academic_credit.credit}}` from the list. How do i achieve this since all the details are inside the ng-repeat??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use a couple of filters: Angular's **[`filter`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)** for filtering details based on their categoryId and one custom filter for summing credits.

```
app.filter('sumCredits', function () {
    return function (details) {
        var sum = 0;
        details.forEach(function (item) {
            sum += item.student_academic_credit.credit;
        });
        return sum;
    };
});

<span class="badge badge-info" 
      ng-bind="mpttdetails | filter:{catagory:{id:node.id}} | sumCredits">
</span>
<div ng-repeat="detail in mpttdetails | filter:{catagory:{id:node.id}}">
    {%verbatim%}
        <li class="list-group-item">
            ...
```

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/c4kaG/)**.

Comment: hi.. great answer. But i dont think the syntax is correct because {{node}} here is from a django mptt tree. Is there another syntax to apply the same filter?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not familiar with django, so I don't know exactly what you mean. I thought `node.id` refers to the `id` property of the `node` object in `$scope`. If I understand correctly, `node.id` is going to come as a hard-coded value from django. In that is the case, the filter will still work as expected (you can replace `node.id` with a hard-coded value and it still works). (In case I misunderstood, just let me know :))

Comment: oh sure no problem. since angular and django both use {{}} for displaying elements, they are separated using the verbatim that i have. the node.id in django is used from the django mptt. I will figure it out . Thank you :)

Comment: hi i am getting the following error. when i tried using the following just to check if it is working. <span class="badge badge-success" ng-bind="mpttdetails | filter:{catagory:{id:25}} | sumCredits">
</span> ....  The error says Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: sumCreditsFilterProvider <- sumCreditsFilter

Comment: Are you sure you defined the `sumCredits` filter on your main module and included the JS file in your HTML ?

Comment: aah..i understood the error. I had the filter defined in my controller by mistake.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the controller that has the service injected, loop through just like ng-repeat is doing and add to your `$scope.sum`.

```
app.controller('WhateverCtrl', function($scope, mptt) {
  // Assuming it's an ajax call
  mptt.getDetails().success(function(mpttdetails) {
    $scope.mpttdetails = mpttdetails;

    // Set sum on scope
    var sum = 0;
    angular.forEach(mpttdetails, function(detail) {
      sum = sum + detail.student_academic_credit.credit;
    });
    $scope.sum = sum;
  });
});
```